# DataGridView.DataError Event, keep changes on row apart from the cell which caused the error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

To clarify what is happening in the DGV before the issue occurs. I load my DGV with data and set the 1st column to the primary key column. Adding and editing data is perfect apart from the scenario below.

When editing an existing row (has multiple columns), lets say 3 in total for reference purposes. i change the values in columns 2 and 3. I then change column 1's value (Primary key column) to that of an existing value within the primary key column. This then fires the DataError event and I handle it accordingly (I am happy with this and how i have handled it apart from 1 thing). At the end of the event the entire rows edited contents revert (change back to the original) and i want to stop this (i set the focus and begin edit on column 1's cell and that begins the edit process again).

currently it will handle the error and do everything i need it to do but i cannot find the event nor stop it from discarding my changes after the DataError event has fired.

could anyone please point me to an event or a way of stopping this discarding of data.

If you require more information please let me know and i will assist. I haven't posted any code as it is not relevant in this instant as i am trying to find the entry point of the event/method that is discarding my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a member on here i found the issue. so basically it boiled down to not committing the values when the CellEndEdit event executes.

```
Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(DataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
If (row Is Nothing OrElse Not row.IsNew) Then
     Validate()
     DataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End If
```

I only execute this on the columns that are not my primary key as i want this value to be reverted and entered into the edit state when the DataError is raised so that the user can change the value or leave it as the original value.

I also check to see if the row is new as this scenario does not happen on new rows.